# Mount(2) write permission on an encrypted partition

Tags: c, permissions, cryptography, mount

```
int mount(const char *source, const char *target,
              const char *filesystemtype, unsigned long mountflags,
              const void *data);
```

I mounted a `crypted partition (crypto_LUKS)` with the `mount(2)` function. 
There is no problem with it. Except that I can't write files in this partition, I can only read 'em. The permission is READ_ONLY.

Do you know a "Mountflags" or something to fix this problem?

I tried with the "Mountflags" MS_RDONLYand the "opposite" one ~MS_RDONLY, it doesn't work.

Thanks.

Comment: Don't you need to flip just the read only bit instead of all the bits?

Comment: Flip, what do you mean? I'm crap at English..

Comment: OK, negating, as you do with the `~` operator. Now you negate *all* of the (64?) bits in `MS_READONLY` when you tried `~MS_READONLY`. But still, *not* specifying `MS_READONLY` should be enough.

Comment: BTW, do you manybe mean `MS_RDONLY` instead of `MS_READONLY`?

Comment: I'm gonna check this out. 
EDIT: I tried with 0 and it didn't work. It's C programming so I must put an argument, I can't just "not specifying" it. Thanks very much for your help tho.
EDIT2: Yes indeed, MS_RDONLY. Typo error.

Comment: Usually you OR flags together, or you specify 0, so in that sense you can not-specify it. You didn't do the `~` trick with another flag, I hope? Please show the code to calculate the mountflags!

Comment: Oh... I screwed up then. What I would like to do is to mount them with the default flags. Do you know which ones are the default flags? I just can't find them..

Comment: That I don't know, which flags are default and not may be more appropriate on a linux forum. I just do crypto normally, but your question was all alone :)

Comment: We finally made it, in fact our school project was to mount a partition write-protected. We misunderstood. Thanks for your help, we finally made our pam_module!

Comment: Glad I could help you out a bit, Oxy.